# How to apply a CSS gradient over a text, from a transparent to an opaque colour

Tags: html, css

Cheers!

I am a newbie in CSS/HTML, but I want to apply a gradient over a text, like that on the image below. How can I implement it with css?

---

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ? And I think you ment [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/opacity), not shadow.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The relevant CSS is on the pseudoelement `:after` of the `<article>` wrapper I used

```css
article {
  position: relative;
}

article:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(to top,
     rgba(255,255,255, 1) 20%, 
     rgba(255,255,255, 0) 80%
  );
  pointer-events: none; /* so the text is still selectable */
}
```

```html
  <article>
      <p>
         Had you stepped on board the Pequod at a certain juncture 
         of this post-mortemizing of the whale; and had you strolled
         forward nigh the windlass, pretty sure am I that you would
         have scanned with no small curiosity a very strange, enigmatical 
         object, which you would have seen there, lying along lengthwise 
         in the lee scuppers. Had you stepped on board the Pequod at a certain 
         juncture of this post-mortemizing of the whale; and had you strolled
         forward nigh the windlass, pretty sure am I that you would
         have scanned with no small curiosity a very strange, enigmatical 
         object, which you would have seen there, lying along lengthwise 
         in the lee scuppers.
      </p>
  </article>
```

Comment: you should make it fixed height to bottom. so 80% of text will stay selectable.

Comment: This won't work if you need to fade out text that is on top of a layer that has opacity (i.e., semi-transparent).

Answer (score 16):

CSS3 text gradients that is only supported by Webkit based browsers like Chrome and Safari. I have used 3 different methods.
check this fiddle first http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/pvU7r/
Try this

```
.article{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

this is working fine in chrome don't know how other browser react. Reference taken from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/

Comment: This is a great little hack. According to CanIUse it works with 95% of users in the UK, and 91% worldwide. Not bad.

Comment: This works in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. Not in IE11, if you require support for that still.

One interesting note is I found that the order in which these are defined actually matter. Keep the background one above the others

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this with the [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) property, though you [may need to](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image#:%7E:text=From%20version%208%2C%20Chrome%20added) add the `-webkit-` prefix.

```css
article {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 16px, red 66px);
  /* 0deg = down, 90deg = left, 180deg = top, 270deg = right */
}
```

```html
  <article>
      <p>
         Had you stepped on board the Pequod at a certain juncture 
         of this post-mortemizing of the whale; and had you strolled
         forward nigh the windlass, pretty sure am I that you would
         have scanned with no small curiosity a very strange, enigmatical 
         object, which you would have seen there, lying along lengthwise 
         in the lee scuppers. Had you stepped on board the Pequod at a certain 
         juncture of this post-mortemizing of the whale; and had you strolled
         forward nigh the windlass, pretty sure am I that you would
         have scanned with no small curiosity a very strange, enigmatical 
         object, which you would have seen there, lying along lengthwise 
         in the lee scuppers.
      </p>
  </article>
```

Comment: this is by far the cleanest solution!